# Trigger click on child when clicking <tr>

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="first"><a href="somelink">Griechenland, Mykonos</a></td>
    <td class="second">test</td>
    <td class="third">test</td>
    <td class="last">699.-</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want when I click the tr, to trigger the click of the `<a>` inside it.

I tried the following but it isn't working:

```
$('tr').click(function() {
    $(this).children('td.first a').click();
});
```

Comment: Does your tr click event fire? Perhaps you need to use event delegation

Comment: It does. The Q has been answered.

Comment: well why dont u simply add the anchor tag inside your tr itself

Comment: @dreamweiver How would you do that? Because anchor tag cannot be direct child of TR

Comment: In theory this concept should trigger an infinite loop. If you click on 'test', the click event will bubble up to the row. Then you catch that, and trigger a click on the link, which will bubble up to the row...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call native DOM click method:

```
$(this).find('td.first a').get(0).click();
```

Comment: Because jQuery doens't trigger native click method on anchor TAG

Comment: @BlekStena - To answer your question as to why your method doesn't work, .children() only looks one level down the DOM, so `.children('td.first a')` won't match anything because only td (or th) elements can be children of tr elements.

Comment: @j08691 that's correct but even calling jQuery click method on anchor tag doesn't make any redirection, default behaviour

Answer (score 2):

If I recall correctly, jQuery's `click()` is only effective on elements that have a jQuery click handler attached to them, and yours do not.

Perhaps an alternative to trying to force a native browser click event is to find the `href` of the link and *simulate* a click by simply navigating to it:

```
$('tr').click(function() {
    window.location = $('td.first a', this).attr('href');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use jquery trigger method.

```
$('tr').click(function() {
    $(this).children('td.first a').trigger( "click" );
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: `trigger('click')` is just the longer version of `click()`. I don't think it will work here.